# How to unnest the repeated/array columns properly in bigquery?

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery, nested

Im trying to unnest two columns associate and manager.
Table sample is given below

```
id | associate | manager
101   Marie      Susan
      Jenie      Paul
```

When i flatten the above using below query

```
select id,associate,manager from table,
unnest(associate) as associate,
unnest(manager) as manager
```

My result will be

```
id | associate | manager
101   Marie      Susan
101   Jenie      Paul
101   Marie      Susan
101   Jenie      Paul
```

The result set is just an example. The values are getting multiplied and displayed unnecessarily.

My expected result is

```
id | associate | manager
101   Marie      Susan
101   Jenie      Paul
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
select id, associate, manager
from your_table, 
unnest(associate) associate with offset
join unnest(manager) manager with offset
using(offset)
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Great. The above solution worked.
However, consider the manager field has null, in that case, joining is failing and zero records displayed.

Comment: Array cannot have null element! But in case if the whole field is a null  - just use `left join`  instead of `join` :o)